# Should we merge [network] & [networking]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merge

Just stumbled upon the two:

- [networking](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) × 62, having a tag-wiki
- [network](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network) × 2, no tag-wiki.

I'd say we should merge `network` into `networking`, and make it a synonym (to avoid it from re-appearing).

Comment: Makes sense to me. There are few enough questions that we can just manually retag them, then create the synonym. Does anyone see any reason not to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done.

With names that are so close to each other, keeping both isn't very useful: if you type `network`, completion will show [networking](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking). I left the synonym [network](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network) for the sake of incoming migrations, since several sites that might plausibly migrate to us use the tag name `network`.

Comment: Thanks, Gilles!